# Branch-per-feature workflow using Mercurial

Tags: version-control, mercurial

We have team of 10 developers who works parallel for different features, sometimes these features use common code sometime no.
And now we're changing our process  to branch-per-feature and it seems mercurial is more suitable for such development.

I see this process so:
1. make release branch (r-b) from default(trunk)
2. make feature branch (f-b) from default(trunk)

When developer thinks his feature is done he can merge f-b to r-b. When it's time to go to QA we merge all finished f-b to r-b and create release for our QAs.

Questions:

1. When QA finds a bug developer should modify his f-b and merge it again to r-b. Does it mean that developer just switch to his f-b and start fixing the bug and then makes simple merge f-b to r-b again?
2. When release is passed QA it goes to PROD - how can we freeze changes? "hg tag" is good choice but someone can update tag if he really wants it.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

If you're going to merging into specific release branches then your feature branches should be branched from the release branch, not the trunk.  It is simpler to merge with the parent branch than a non-parent branch.

1) If you really want to do feature branches then each bug would have its own branch.  This will help keep bug fixes separate from new features.  After all, it's branch-per-feature not branch-per-developer.

2) Hg tag is what I have used.  You are right that someone change move a tag if they really want to, but tags are versioned and you can install hooks on the main hg repo to throw alerts if a tag is moved.  I really wouldn't worry about tags being moved unless you can't trust your developers, in which case you are screwed.

Comment: We have weekly release and it's really hard to know if F-b#1 comes to this release r-#1. And in this case I want to move f-b#1 to the next release r-#2 or next-next release r-#3. In this case developer just update his f-b#1 from trunk(after release we merge r-b to trunk to have last stable build as trunk) after r-#1 and continue to working. I don't know if's good decision from VSC view but it's easy to understand for developers that all f-b makes from trunk and they don't care in which release their f-b comes.

Comment: 1. I don't like Branch-per-bug because I don't need this branch - I need well-done feature. And again it's easy to understand for developers and build masters to work in terms of branch-per-feature. it's much easy to see in JIRA and see feature issue status and understand that this feature can't be integrated in r-b or it can. But with branch-per-bug build master should find all related branches. But if it's the best way for VSC to manage history/merges/etc then I have no choice

Answer (score 2):

The answer to your first question is 'yes'.

The best way to freeze for release is to have a separate release clone that only the release manager can push/pull changesets to.  Just because you're using branches doesn't mean multiple-clones don't have a place in your workflow.  Have a clone that QA does final pre-flight testing on to which developers can't push changes makes for a great firewall.

Also, consider using bookmarks for your feature branches.  Since, as I'm sure you know, Mercurial named branch names never go away the git-like bookmarks work well for sort lived concepts like features and bugs.

Comment: what is the benefits of bookmarks? for me named branches are more easy things and they're always stored in mercurial.

Comment: The benefit, or more accurately, difference is their ephemeral nature.  They're stored in the repo, they can be pushed and pulled, but they can also be deleted.  They're mostly like "tags that auto-advance".  A lot of people find named branches frustrating for short lived things since they can't ever be deleted.  If having 1000 branches doesn't both you (it doesn't bother me) then there's nothing wrong with named branches.

Comment: I need to read mercurial manuals more deeply to understand how bookmarks work. And you can delete named branch by "hg commit --close-branch"

Comment: That doesn't delete it.  That hides it from some views and not others.  Again, if you're happy with named branches that's great, I just see a lot of people say "How do I get rid of a branch name entirely?" and don't like the answer "You can't."  A changeset is always on the branch on which it's created -- branch name is a permanent part of any changeset -- which I think is a great thing, but not everyone does, and those folks should use bookmarks.  Plenty of good options; no hard rules.

Comment: Hiding is OK for me as developer - I don't care how it works it's even better that named branch can be re-found at any time. It's always better to have something that you don't need than don't have something that you really need :) Thanks for answers.